# HTML & CSS - put <link> tag outside of the <head>

Tags: html, css, performance, hyperlink, head

Is it ok to put the `<link>` to a css file out of the `<head/>` tag, for example in the footer side?

Which are bad and good results of this?

I ask this, cause actually i have a css file which doesn't styles anything but brings just some css3 animations to my website, so i would like to put it to the end of the html just for performance reason...

thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Style sheets are linked in the `<head>` so that the browser can style the HTML and render it as it goes. If you put the style information at the bottom of the document the browser will have to restyle and render the whole document from the top again.

This firstly, takes longer, and secondly, looks really ugly.

This differs from included scripts as scripts will block loading until they are done, so you load them as late as possible in the process.

Comment: can you please check my question updated, can you also specify why this takes "longer" ?

Comment: If a browser has to wait until it reaches the end of a document before it can apply any style information it will likely have to render the page twice - hence it is slower. In your specific case, now you explained it more clearly, there's probably no performance penalty, but if the CSS is relatively small there's probably no performance gain, either.

Answer (score 24):

According to the W3 specs, `<link>` tags are only supposed to go in the `<head>` section:

### **References**

**For HTML 4.01:** http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK

**For HTML5:** http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

### Validation Issues: Updated October 27, 2017

Back in 2013, if you put a `link` tag within the `body` of the HTML document, it would not validate using [validate.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/) with rules based on HTML 4.01.

(You can try out HTML 4.01 versus HTML 5.0 validation at https://validator.nu)

On a first reading, the HTML 5.0 specification document seems to imply that `link`'s should appear only in the `head` element of the document.  However, if you validate using a HTML 5.0 validator, then the documents appears okay even if you have a `link` in the flow content.

The best explanation for this discrepancy may be as follows.

If you read the MDN documentation for the `link` entry ([MDN Link entry)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link), you see that if the `link` element has an `itemprop` attribute, then the `link` can appear in flow and phrasing content, thus, in the `body`.

This may be the reason why HTML 5.0 validators do not issue a warning even if the `itemprop` attribute is not present.

The `itemprop` is part of the microdata specification and is relatively new ([read about HTML Microdata)](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#dfn-attr-itemprop) and it is worth reading.

For the moment, one could add a `link` to a stylesheet within the `body`, but it is not clear what the advantages are.

Comment: ok, clear, so this will trown a standard error validation error right?

Comment: I don't see any validation errors for using `<link>` outside of `<head>`.

Comment: The HTML5 spec doesn't mention that link elements only goes inside the head element. That's a lie. And as Matt is pointing out, the w3 validator for HTML5 as nothing against it either.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old discussion, but I think it's worth noting in here that Google Pagespeed Insights actually now (2017) recommends [deferring the loading of large CSS files until below the fold](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) to ensure they don't block loading of html.

Comment: Well, that's actually a *not good* recommendation - it may not block *loading* of the HTML, but it will prevent *accurate rendering* of the page until the CSS is loaded - and as @user1864610 pointed out, it will cause the page to be ***re-rendered*** when the CSS *is* loaded - which will ***increase*** the perceived page load time.

Comment: The recommendation is to inline the "CSS necessary to render above-the-fold content".

Answer (score 3):

WHATWG HTML Standard allows **`<link>`** in the body in [quite many specified cases](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok).

As for "reasonableness" of placing `<link>` before the `</body>`, recently I've used it for preloading some big images in gallery:

```
<link rel="preload" href="images/big/01.jpg" as="image">
```

So when user clicked on the thumbnail usually there was no need to wait for server response because image was already loaded into browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it's okay with HTML5 specifications to put a link element inside the body element. If it's a bad or good idea depends on what your linking. If it's not crucial to render the first view of your site then I'd consider it a good idea to load it as late as possible.

Comment: According to the HTML5 Specification, Section 4.2.4, the `link`element is part of the Metadata Content category and can be used where metadata content is expected, and that is in the `head` element. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element).  The `body` element contains flow content and a `link` is not considered to be flow content according to the specification.  Based on browser behavior, it may be okay to put a `link` within the `body` element, but this is different from stating that the specification allows it.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I did some research based on your comment and I updated my original answer (from 2013) to reflect the new thinking that is coming out of HTML 5.0, thank you for your help!

Comment: Marc: You may be right but I don't see the statement "Where metadata content is expected." defined anywhere. If you compare the spec for `link` with `meta` for example, they explicitly mention that in some cases `meta` can only be used inside `head`.

Answer (score 1):

You must put `<!DOCTYPE html>` before any `<link>` tags.   From experience, it can cause some pages to malfunction.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why is that neccessary? What makes you think that the OP didn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

As everything in software development, things change. Now it's considered good practice CSS in the body, something like:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- HTTP/2 push this resource, or inline it, whichever's faster -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site-header.css">
  <header>…</header>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/article.css">
  <main>…</main>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/comment.css">
  <section class="comments">…</section>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/about-me.css">
  <section class="about-me">…</section>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site-footer.css">
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

Source: https://jakearchibald.com/2016/link-in-body/

Comment: I'm trying to find more examples of this use. It makes sense to me to do it that way with HTTP/2, but I didn't find many people talking about it.